# Ionic 2 not getting the headers in the http response

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2

I am making http request to my REST API from Ionic 2. I am using the same code as I use in angular 4. In angular 4 I get all the response headers after my request, but in the Ionic 2 I don't get the headers.
Here is my code:

When I click the login button I call the **login(user)** from login component:

```
login(user: User){
    this.showLoader();
    this.authService.login(user.username, user.password).subscribe(
        (data) => {
            var currentUser = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentUser'));
            this.loading.dismiss();
            this.navCtrl.setRoot(HomePage);
        }, (error) => {
            console.log('error ',error);
            this.loading.dismiss();
            if(error.status == 401){
                console.log(JSON.stringify(error, null, 2));
            }
        });
};
```

**auth.service.ts:**

```
login(username: string, password: string) {
    return this.http.post(apiUrl + 'login', JSON.stringify({ username: username, password: password }))
        .map((response: Response) => {
            let user = {
                "username": username,
                "token": response.headers.get('x-auth'),
            };
            localStorage.setItem("currentUser", JSON.stringify(user));
            console.log("authService user: ", JSON.stringify(user));
            console.log("response header:", response.headers);
        });
}
```

The request is successful and here are the headers I get:

[image]

but the REST API (built in spring) also returns `x-auth: token` which is not available.

Comment: are you sure the auth header is returned? have you tested with a rest client?

Comment: I am using the same rest api in angular 4 and I get all the headers.More than that, I am using the same code. Also tested in postman and also getting all the headers. I have read several posts about the same problem and not sure if there is a work around for it. It's a bug from Ionic